# Query assigning a null to a column if a dependent column is also null in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains dozens of athletes and the hours they spent at the gym everyday. My goal is to calculate their total hours in a month. They were supposed to go every day, and if they missed any day (null for that day), I want the entire total hours column for that athlete to display null, not the sum of their monthly hours. I have two columns, daily_hours, and total_hours, which is defined as sum(daily_hours). My query is this, however it is giving me an error in syntax

```
select case
  when daily_hours is null then total_hours = null 
  else total_hours end as name, total_hours 
from (select name, sum(daily_hours) as total_hours from athletes group by name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues, your case expression is incorrect and you're missing an alias for your derived table - however you can simplify by using a case expression in combination with *coalesce* to determin your NULL values:

```
select name, 
  case when 
    Min(Coalesce(daily_hours,-1)) > 0 then Sum(daily_hours)
  else 
    null 
  end as total_hours 
from athletes 
group by name;
```

Comment: when you say (daily_hours,-1), what does that mean?

Comment: This replaces the NULL (which is ignored by aggregations) with -1, then NULLS can be "seen" and used by the case expression.